# Connect Sagemaker to RDS db

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to AWS. All I know is that the Postgre database is hosted in AWS RDS. I want to build an ML model using AWS Sagemaker. I am not sure how to get the data from AWS RDS so that I can use it for building the ML model.
I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways which you can follow to achieve this. Below are couple of options that you can use:

1. [Export](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/) Amazon RDS/Amazon Aurora snapshots to Amazon S3 as Apache Parquet then build models using SageMaker.
2. [Directly](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-aurora-supports-machine-learning-directly-from-database/) connect to [RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-ml.html) and build you models using SQL in Sageaker

Comment: Thank you. However, having a complete snapshot in S3 can consume a lot of space as the DB will keep on increasing day by day.
So, point 2 seems better. Can you suggest a way for that?

Comment: Does it have to be with Aurora?